# Desktop environment that stacks programs in the task bar

Tags: linux, desktop, desktop-environment

I'm currently on Linux Mint with Cinnamon and completely abandoned windows a couple months ago. 
The only one thing that I'm currently missing from windows is the stacking of several instances of one program in the task bar as seen here with firefox:

[image]

On windows you can also right-click the stacked icons and close all instances of that program.

Is there a Linux desktop or addon that offers the same functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [DockbarX](https://github.com/M7S/dockbarx). It supports rich functionality of Windows Superbar and OS X Dockbar and much more (progress indicators; number of application's notifications, f. e., unread mail; window stacking; window previews with custom buttons; etc.) Can be run in any graphical environment as it is a standalone application.

Answer (score 3):

KDE4 can do it: right-click on the task bar, select Task Manager Settings, and change Grouping to "By Program Name" as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: +1 and there's an option to group things only when the taskbar becomes full, but in some environments the groupings may become a little peculiar. An example with PC-BSD 11.0-CURRENTNOV2015: [KDE Task Manager grouping](https://forums.pcbsd.org/thread-20571.html)